# Starting Oracle Apex server with a user that isnt SYS

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have installed Apex on a database (through docker) and i want to use a user over that SYS for it. I created a user with DBA privilages and tried to put its connection string instead of the SYS user, but it just fails then.

Can Apex server use a user that isnt SYS for it? If so, what am i missing for it to work?
Thanks!

Example of what i did:
Original connection string: `sys/#SysPassword#//localhost:1521/XEPDB1`
New user connection string: `user4apex/#UserPassword#//localhost:1521/XEPDB1`

Comment: I think the documentation specifically states it needs SYS. If so, then... well it needs to be SYS.

Comment: Can you link to the place that says it? i know it requires DBA privileges for the installation and potential updates, but i haven't seen specifically that a user with privileges similar or identical to SYS doesn't suffice

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/23.1/htmig/downloading-installing-apex.html#GUID-7E432C6D-CECC-4977-B183-3C654380F7BF